# Is there a way to automatically get track of installed packages and dependencies?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, logging

There are packages I installed using 'apt-get install', that installed also all its dependencies. If I want to remove it after some time, I would remove its dependencies as well. Now I do not trust 'apt-get autoremove' or deborphan, since they caused me some problems in the past. So I thought to get manually track of installed packages every time I install something.

Is there not a smarter way to automatically monitor / log installed packages?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the fastest and most handy solution to keep track of dependancies is to use a package manager, like 'synaptic' for Gnome and 'muon' for KDE.

From the command line, you should check the 'apt-rdepends' or 'apt-cache depends' commands

Comment: The problem is I do not truest automatic tools that check dependencies, as I said in the answer. I'm searching for a way to log my installs, or the log path if it already exists.

Comment: The purposes of those package managers are to install, remove and, well, manage packages. To install a piece of software and make it work correctly, they also need to correctly manage dependencies. For every package, they can show you all other packages required to make it work, and also all the contents (with installation path). And they also mantain a chronology of package management activity

Comment: They are supposed to do that, yes. But, for example, some time ago apt-get wanted to autoremove a package of Sage. I never updated Sage after I installed it, so it seemed strange to me, but I've autoremoved it. Indeed after I trusted apt-get, Sage didn't work any more and I have to reinstall the package. That time I noticed it, but what if that happened with a package like libsomething1.1-3-ubuntu1? That's why I'm searching for a install log.

Comment: Could you please add links to these sofwares?

Answer (score 0):

I use **aptitude** because it tracks dependencies and removes unused packages automatically.

I also would like to know if Muon also tracks dependencies, but I have not found any info about this for now.